# Can I use DRF-SPECTACULAR for external API?

Tags: django, swagger

Currently using drf-spectacular with no issues on my site. However, I need to also document some APIs for separate app. Is it possible to use a json or yaml file to produce some swagger/redoc documentation?

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to do it?

Comment: No, haven't had any success yet.